# display loading spinner and prevent from any other action on the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, loading

I have a asp.net MVC3 web application in which i search for a certain criteria and display the search results in a grid, on click of the row in the grid i load the results in a new page. Meanwhile when i click on the row in the table i am displaying a loading image on the top of the table. I am displaying spinner on row selection.

```
function onRowSelected(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
   // populate some data here
    $("#spinner").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Search/GetResults",
        data: populate the data to be sent,
        dataType: "text json",
        success:
        function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data != "Success") {
                ShowError(data);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "/Search/Test/";
               }
        },
        error:
        function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error Occured!");

        }

    });
}
```

and the code for spinner is:

```
<div id='spinner' style='display:none;'><center><img alt='' src='../../Images/loading.gif' title='Loading...' /><b>Loading...</b></center> </div>
```

My problem is, when the user selects one row and when the loading symbol is displayed, He is able to click on another row. I want to prevent the user from clicking or selecting anything on the page once the loading spinner is visible. Any help

**UPDATE**:

My problem is not with the loading image position.. i want it to display as an overlay or something of that sort so that the page behind will be grayed out and user can't select anything

Comment: In addition to the CSS solutions people provided, maybe you can unbind the related events from your table rows. Or even make them disabled temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a javascript variable, say `bool_spinner`, which is by default `false` but set to `true` when the spinner is shown, and gets set back to `false` after the data is loaded.

You can then test this variable inside your functions (like inside onRowSelected) to control what happens depending on the spinner's state.

Then you can maybe use something like this (untested) to prevent other active HTML elements, (like links and form submit buttons) from reacting when you click on the page:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if (bool_spinner) e.preventDefault();
}
```

EDIT: You can also check exactly what has been clicked if you need to, like this:

```
  var target = $(e.target);  
  if (target.is("#tGrid")) {
      etc.        
  }
```

UPDATE: Actually, you don't even need to set a new script variable, you can just directly [test the state](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) of your spinner:

```
if ($('#spinner').is(':hidden')) { 
  etc. 
}
```

Comment: instead of adding a flag i want to display the loading symbol on a kind of overlay.

Comment: @rutwikreddy As mentioned in this thread, you can apply css to your spinner div which will turn it into such an overlay.  Here is also a jQuery "block user interaction" plugin which is possibly what you need: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 2):

just add the css

```
  #spinner
    {
        background: url("image") repeat scroll #AAA;
        opacity: 0.3;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:2000;
    }
```

hope this works

Comment: My problem is not with the loading image position.. i want it to display as an overlay or something like that so that the page behind will be grayed out and user can't select anything

Comment: yes.. i understand your situation. by giving the css of the div with id spinner as position:absolute and with background property this div will blind all contents in the html and display the spinner..

Comment: doesn't work in my case :( i am still able to select the table cells

Comment: what also helps is adding "pointer-events: all;" - without this extra line of CSS, I was sometimes still able to click through.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding css style to your `#spinner`(the height and width attributes may not be necessary):

```
#spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999; // puts your div on top on others
}
```